# unittests require google.appengine.ext

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, python-unittest

I have Google App Engine Python SDK installed and working with the GUI.  However, now I am locally trying to test my app using unittest in a virtualenv.  Everything is fine until I try to access google.appengine.ext.testbed.  How do I access the SDK in this context?  My error is included below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 4, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import testbed
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

update:  In further research, I've found that GAE "doesn't play well" with virtualenv.  Subsequently, I installed all of my dependencies globally.  The issue remains unchanged, so I think we can rule out virtualenv as the culprit.

Comment: Where are your test files in relation to your project?

Comment: Same directory.  tests.py can find main.py and main.py can find tests.py